# NSTextField force becomeFirstResponder removes text

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa, nstextfield

Using NSTextField on Custom NSTableCellView.

When the user presses anywhere on the cell, I would like `NSTextField` to become the first responder.
When I do, the text disappears, and the user needs to press any keyboard key for it to come back, how to disable this behavior?

*Code:*

```
    override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        super.mouseDown(with: event)
        if (event.clickCount == 2) {
            self.beginEditing()
        } else {
            self.endEditing()
        }
    }

    private func beginEditing() {
        self.lblTitle.isEditable = true
        self.window?.makeFirstResponder(self.lblTitle)
        self.lblTitle.backgroundColor = Colors.clear
        self.lblTitle.borderColor = Colors.clear
    }

    private func endEditing() {
        self.lblTitle.isEditable = false
        self.lblTitle.backgroundColor = Colors.red
    }
```

Comment: Please read the discussion part of the documentation of `becomeFirstResponder`.

Comment: @Willeke I'm sorry, this code was after several attempts. I did try with the window before the first responder, with no luck. Updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing this lines solved it

```
self.lblTitle.backgroundColor = Colors.clear
self.lblTitle.borderColor = Colors.clear
```